# vue 2 jest coverage is incorrect

Tags: vue.js, code-coverage, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library

I have setup unit testing using installation instructions from https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/

Tests are running properly. But the coverage is coming incorrectly.

In the report it is showing it has only 1 statement, 1 function, 2 branches for some reason.

It's not showing coverage for all the lines. It shows coverage in the first line and doesn't show coverage anywhere else. Don't know what's the issue is here.

I'm using Bootstrap-vue to render components. Can this create an issue with coverage? I'm asking this because the example.spec.js that came for the helloworld component is showing coverage correctly.

[image]

my dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
```

Comment: Hi, can you add more details. How are you running your tests? What code coverage tool are you using? Show example code and example coverage report.

Comment: I have the same problem with jest, vue2. I am running test using `vue-cli-service test:unit`. Looks like it is treating component config (`export default {<config>}`) as a single line of code.